# The button to update the 'hp' variable in my website works internally, but for some reason the javascript doesn't update the footer on first click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, flask

The variables are updated internally for every click of the button, as it should, but the footer only starts updating after the first click, and when I switch to the players page to place a "bounty", the first click ends up decreasing the footer value by 1 (which should be the tipping function) and only decreasing the hp value by 10 after the first click. What might be the cause of this?

**app.py:**

```
@app.route("/dealers", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def dealers():
    if request.method == "POST":
        id = int(request.form['user_id'])

        #initialize rows with user data
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])

        # making sure user has enough hp
        if rows[0]["hp"] < 1:
            return jsonify({'success': False})
        
        # minus users hp and add dealers hp
        db.execute("UPDATE users SET hp = hp - 1, lucky = lucky + 1 WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])
        db.execute("UPDATE users SET hp = hp + 1 WHERE id = ?", id)

        session["hp"] = rows[0]["hp"]
        hp = session["hp"]

        return jsonify({'success': True, 'hp': hp})
    else:
        return render_template("dealers.html")

@app.route("/players", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def players():
    if request.method == "POST":
        id = int(request.form['user_id'])

        #initialize rows with user data
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])
        
        # minus users hp and add dealers hp
        db.execute("UPDATE users SET hp = hp - 10, lucky = lucky + 10 WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])
        db.execute("UPDATE users SET bounty = bounty + 1 WHERE id = ?", id)

        session["hp"] = rows[0]["hp"]
        hp = session["hp"]

        return jsonify({'success': True, 'hp': hp})
    else:
        players = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY hp")
        # add OFFSET int for skipping first few users^
        
        return render_template("players.html", players=players)
```

**script.js:**

```
function tip(user_id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/dealers',
        data: {'user_id': user_id},
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.success) {
                $("#dialog-message").dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        Ok: function() {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                });
                $("#dialog-message").text("You have successfully tipped");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#dialog-message").dialog("close");
                }, 4000); // close dialog after 5 seconds

                // update HP value in #value-container element
                if (data.hp !== undefined) {
                    $('#value-container').text("HP: " + data.hp);
                }
            } 
    });
}

function placeBounty(user_id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/players',
        data: {'user_id': user_id},
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.success) {
                $("#dialog-message").dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        Ok: function() {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                });
                $("#dialog-message").text("You have successfully placed a bounty!");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#dialog-message").dialog("close");
                }, 4000); // close dialog after 5 seconds 
                $('#value-container').html("HP: " + data.hp);
            }
```

**layout.html:**

```
//some code
<footer>
    <div id="value-container"> HP: {{ session["hp"] }} </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
So apparently in my app.py file, I forgot to re-update rows with the user data AFTER updating the hp variable, which was why there is a delay when you first click the button.